# Why doesn't this template function call work inside this function?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

The following code doesn't compile, I am trying to figure out how to calculate the size of an array that is passed into a function and can't seem to get the syntax correct.

The error I am getting is :

```
Error   1   error C2784: 'size_t getSize(T (&)[SIZE])' : could not deduce template argument for 'T (&)[SIZE]' from 'const byte []' 16   1 sizeofarray
```

Here is the source code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename T, size_t SIZE>
size_t getSize(T (&)[SIZE]) {
    return SIZE;
}

typedef std::uint_fast8_t byte;

void processArray(const byte b[])
{
    size_t size = getSize(b); // <- line 16 where error occurs
    // do some other stuff
}

int main(const int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    byte b[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    printf("%u\n", getSize(b));
    processArray(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to make `processArray` a template.

Comment: This happens because arrays decay to pointers.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - to be technical, the **name** of an array decays into a pointer to its first element. Arrays don't decay.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's too much typing :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - yeah, I know. But this is an area where beginners get really confused.

Comment: yes I realize the name `b[]` decays to a pointer, I just couldn't get the template magic to work correctly, thanks for all the quick responses, I will pick a oldest correct answer as soon as the system lets me.

Comment: @PeteBecker It's clear from the question that the OP is well past the beginners stage :-)

Comment: @PeteBecker: Interesting -- do you have a reference on this?  I'm not sure I know the distinction you are making.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Maybe you are distinguishing a value of type array from the array type itself.

Comment: @VaughnCato - no, the distinction is precisely that the name of an array decays, in most contexts, into a pointer to its first element. That's ancient C, and it makes it possible to write functions that take arrays as arguments without having to duplicate code for different size arrays. `strcpy`, for example, doesn't need to know the size of the array that it's copying.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Of course, the consequence then is that your function doesn't "take arrays" at all.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Hmm..  What you are saying would seem to imply that the array has to have a name for it to decay, but a function might return a reference to an array, and that reference can also decay to a pointer, but doesn't have a name.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - sure it does. I can call it with an array, so it takes arrays as arguments.

Comment: @VaughnCato - no, there's no decay when you use a reference to an array. That's why the template in the original code works.

Comment: @PeteBecker: No, you call it with a pointer because, as you have been explaining your very own self, the array name decays. There is no function that takes an array by value.

Comment: @PeteBecker: ok, maybe I'm getting the term "decay" wrong.  I was thinking you were talking about how a value of type T[n] is implicitly converted to type T*.

Comment: @VaughnCato: That is array name decay, yes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - `int x[3]; f(x);` Clearly I'm calling `f` with an array. The details of how that call is done don't change that.

Comment: @PeteBecker: No. You're calling `f` with a pointer to the first element of `x`. You just didn't need to write that out explicitly at the call site, but the call site is not all there is to the semantics of a function call; look at the declaration of `f`. Overload resolution and array decay are both _part of the call_. Besides, you said "take arrays" and you certainly can't claim that that is true. You could almost claim that the language's overload resolution mechanism is "taking" an array, but `f` never does.

Comment: @VaughnCato - `T[n]` becoming `T*` is, indeed, what "decay" refers to. It is **not** an implicit conversion, though; it's **decay**, and happens in almost all contexts where you use the name of an array.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - when I pass an array to a function I'm calling that function with an array. `int i; void f(char); f(i);` here, I'm calling `f` with an `int`. Same for an array.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I'm referring to section 4.2.1 of the C++03 standard, which states "An lvalue or rvalue of type 'array of N T' or 'array of unknown bound of T' can be converted to an rvalue of type 'pointer to T'.  The result is a pointer to the first element of the array."

Comment: @VaughnCato - you're right, it's a standard conversion.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Regarding your conversation with Vaughn, in fact the term "decay" doesn't appear even once in the standard, if we're going to be nitpicking.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - actually, it does. In the C++11 standard there's a template function named `decay_copy` which forces decay to occur (indirectly). But your point is well taken: "decay" is the informal term that's been used since time immemorial to name what happens in most contexts when the name of an array is used.

Comment: Please take all arguments to chat. Arguments don't do well in comments. A person coming to this question from google wants to see a question and an answer. If anything written here clarifies an existing question or answer, please edit the appropriate response. Otherwise, please clean up your comments.  If no one takes action, I'll clean up these comments tomorrow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want this to work, you need to make processArray be a template as well:

```
template <size_t size>
void processArray(const byte (&b)[size])
{
    // do some other stuff
}
```

C++ does not allow passing arrays by value.  If you have a function like this:

```
void f(int a[5]);
```

It may look like you are passing an array by value, but the language has a special rule that says a parameter of this form is just another way of saying:

```
void f(int *a);
```

So the size of the array is not part of the type at all.  This is behavior inhereted from C.  Fortunately, C++ has references, and you can pass a reference to an array, like this:

```
void f(int (&a)[5]);
```

This way, the size of your array is preserved.

Now, the only remaining trick is to make the function generic, so it can work on any size array.

```
template <size_t n> void f(int (&a)[n]);
```

Now, new versions of the function that take references to arrays of different sizes can be generated automatically for you, and the size can be accessed through the template parameter.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Ah -- I've added some explanation.  Let me know if that is clear.

Comment: awesome explanation, I wish I could up vote and accept this answer twice!

Answer (score 6):

As the argument to a function, `const byte b[]` is treated just like `const byte *b`. There is no compile-time information about the size of the array that the function was called with.

Comment: Incidentally, `const byte b[8]` is also treated just like `const byte *b`.

Answer (score 5):

To pass a reference to the array, you need to make `processArray` a template and use the same technique. If you don't pass in a reference, the parameter is a pointer, and pointer types don't have array size information.

```
template<size_t size>
void processArray(const byte (&b)[size]) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**This is the canonical example** of why you should use a function template like `getSize` rather than `sizeof`, for determining array size.

- With `sizeof`, you'd have gotten the size of a pointer and been none the wiser.
- But, this way, you get a compilation error to point out your mistake.

What was the mistake? It was having a function parameter `const T arg[]` and thinking that this means `arg` is an array. It's not. This is unfortunate syntax from C that is *precisely equivalent* to `const T* arg`. *You get a pointer.*

This is also why some people think — incorrectly — that "arrays are pointers". They are not. It's just this specific syntax.